# Do monster kills outside of the mines count toward the Monster Eradication Goals?

Tags: stardew-valley

Some monsters can be found outside of the mines. For example, slimes can be found in the

> Secret Wood.

Does killing these monsters count toward the [Monster Eradication Goals](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Adventurer%27s_Guild#Monster_Eradication_Goals)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, all monsters count towards the goal. They do not have to be killed in the mines. From the wiki [page on slimes](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Slimes):

> All Slimes in the game count towards this goal

Even farmed slimes will count!